# Send output of Hadoop streaming job to STDOUT

Tags: python, apache, hadoop, mapreduce

For streaming jobs you have to specify an output directory. What if I wanted to output the results of the mapper to stdout instead of an HDFS directory. Is this possible? I want to do this so I can pipe to other programs.

Answer (score 0):

I have written many streaming jobs within hadoop. It is not clear what you expect your custom pipeline to do here.

Let us take a closer look, assuming you wrote the mapper/reducer in python (change from .py to .sh for shell script for example):

```
hadoop jar hadoop-*streaming*.jar 
-file mapper.py    -mapper mapper.py \
-input /user/myuser/input/* -output /user/myuser/output
```

In this case the output is going to hdfs - which is what you said you do **not** want.

So if we instead sent the output to stdout - then the problem is:  **how do you handle that the output is generated by multiple mappers**?

Here is an idea:  why not just "go with the flow" here?  Let the output go to hdfs. Add a **TotalOrderPartitioner** reducer to combine all the output files. Then you csn do hdfs -cat on the output result.

Comment: I can't speak for the asker, but I'd like to use stdout instead of hdfs because I'm running a aggregation task with a very small output so it seems super wasteful (in terms of overhead and also just block-size) to put it ~128 bytes on HDFS.